# ASP.NET MVC3 - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm relatively new to .NET and MVC3. I'm having some trouble with the above error message when trying to add an instance of an object. Below is my code:

KeyDate class

```
public class KeyDate
{
    [Key]
    public int KeyID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000), Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event End Date")]
    public DateTime? EventEndDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Course ID")]
    public int? CourseID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event ID")]
    public int? EventID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Deleted By")]
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

Association class

```
public class Association
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("KeyDate")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int KeyID { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Category")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual KeyDate KeyDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the error in my Controller posted below

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(KeyDate keyDate, int topic)
    {
        keyDate.Created = DateTime.Now;
        keyDate.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

        // Create topic association
        Association keyDateTopic = new Association();
        keyDateTopic.CategoryID = topic;
        keyDate.Associations.Add(keyDateTopic); // <-- Object reference... error here

        repository.Add(keyDate);
        repository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I have Googled this for ages, and have been following ScottGu's "Code First with Existing Database" example in which the code is quite similar, but I have had no luck. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Assosiactions List needs to be instantiated before adding items to it.

Best practice is to do this from within the constructor.

```
public class KeyDate
{
...
    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
    public KeyDate()
    {
       Associations = new List<Association>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works. All part of the learning process... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`Associations` is null. It has not been initialised.

Add a constructor for `KeyDate` and init it in there:

```
public KeyDate()
{
     Associations = new List<Association>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `keyDate.Associations` is null.

Change

```
keyDate.Associations.Add(keyDateTopic);
```

to

```
if ( keyDate.Associations == null)
{
   keyDate.Associations = new Collection<Association>();
}

keyDate.Associations.Add(keyDateTopic);
```

Comment: Hi sll. When tracing through the code, I can see that keyDate.Associations is null. I'm not sure how I set this to an instance of an object.

Comment: If collection of associations is null you can manually cinstantiate it using `keyDate.Associations = new Collection<Association>()`

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

It looks like `keyDate.Associations` is null

You have several ways to solve this

#### Sample

- Create the `ICollection` in your ActionMethod.

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(KeyDate keyDate, int topic)
  {
      keyDate.Created = DateTime.Now;
      keyDate.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

      // Create topic association
      Association keyDateTopic = new Association();
      keyDateTopic.CategoryID = topic;

      // create this list
      keyDate.Associations = new List<Association>();

      keyDate.Associations.Add(keyDateTopic); // <-- Object reference... error here

      repository.Add(keyDate);
      repository.Save();

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  ```
- **OR** Add a constructor to your `KeyDate` class like this

  ```
  public class KeyDate
  {
      public KeyDate()
      {
          // create this list
          this.Associations = new List<Association>();
      }

      [Key]
      public int KeyID { get; set; }

      [StringLength(1000), Required]
      public string Title { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string Description { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Event Date")]
      public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Event End Date")]
      public DateTime? EventEndDate { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Course ID")]
      public int? CourseID { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Event ID")]
      public int? EventID { get; set; }

      public DateTime Created { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Created By")]
      public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

      public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Deleted By")]
      public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Comment: `keyDate` is not null since he already accessed it in the first line of the method body `keyDate.Created = `