# Assigning one Table ID to another Table ID Like Asp.Net Identity AspNetUserRole

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2013

Hi i have 3 model class setup `Group`

```
Public Class Group
    Public Property Id As Long
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property CoverImgUrl As String
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Profile() As ICollection(Of Profile)
        Get

        End Get

    End Property
End Class
```

`Profile`

```
Public Class Profile
    Public Property Id As Long
    <Required>
    <MaxLength(20)>
    <Display(Name:="First Name")>
    Public Property FirstName As String
    <Required>
    <MaxLength(20)>
    <Display(Name:="Last Name")>
    Public Property LastName As String
 Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Group() As ICollection(Of Group)
        Get

        End Get

    End Property
```

and  `GroupMembers`.

```
Public Class GroupMembers
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Overridable Property Group() As Group
    Public Overridable Property GroupId() As String
    Public Overridable Property Profile() As Profile
    Public Overridable Property ProfileId() As String
End Class
```

i ran the `Update-Database` command which updated my database and created a table `ProfileGroup` like asp.net `AspNetUserRole`.

[image]

With the progress so far how can i assign one group to a profile i created like asp.net uses the `UserManager.AddToRole` method to assign a user to a role or any global best practice to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to set up a many-to-many relationship between `Profile` and `Group`. However, you're going about it all wrong.

First, traditionally, you don't actually define a class for the intermediary table, `GroupMembers` in this case, unless you need a payload, i.e. additional data on the relationship. In your posted code, there's no payload on the relationship, so you're just making your life more difficult this way. Assuming you wanted to keep things as they are, though, you would need to set up your classes like:

```
Public Class Group
    ...

    Public Overridable Property Profiles As ICollection(Of GroupMember)

End Class

Public Class Profile
    ...

    Public Overridable Property Groups As ICollection(Of GroupMember)

End Class

Public Class GroupMember
    Public Property GroupId As String
    Public Overridable Property Group As Group

    Public Property ProfileId As String    
    Public Overridable Property Profile As Profile    
End Class
```

This will then be enough for Entity Framework to discern the relationships and create the appropriate tables with the appropriate foreign keys. However, you would be forced to access the `Profile`/`Group` indirectly, i.e. `profile.Groups.First().Group`. Whereas, with an implicit join table, you could just do `profile.Groups.First()`.

So, in order to have an implicit join table, you would just need the following classes:

```
Public Class Group
    ...

    Public Overridable Property Profiles As ICollection(Of Profile)

End Class

Public Class Profile
    ...

    Public Overridable Property Groups As ICollection(Of Group)

End Class
```

Notice that the `GroupMember` class goes away completely. Entity Framework will still see this as a many-to-many and create a table, most likely named `dbo.GroupProfiles`. If you're not happy with the table name, you can declare it using fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Profile)().
    HasMany(Function(t) t.Groups).
    WithMany(Function(t) t.Profiles).
    Map(Sub(m)
            m.ToTable("GroupMembers")
        End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and well understood. now i want to enter value to this created relationship table `ProfileGroups`. Like i have aded some groups and wish to relate a profile to a created group. what will be the right linq query. thanks

Comment: Use either `profile.Groups.Add(group);` or `group.Profiles.Add(profile);`. Then just call `context.SaveChanges();` to persist.

Comment: Thanks for your time i did this `Dim group = db.Group.Where(Function(x) x.Name = "GroupName").First
                profile.Group.Add(group)
                db.Profile.Add(profile)
                db.SaveChanges()` and have this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You're not doing proper null-checking. Somewhere, something is null and you're trying to access a property or method on it.

Comment: Actually, since `profile` is a new class instance here, most likely its `Group` property is null. You need to initialize the collection before you can add to it. It's really only problem when creating, as Entity Framework pretty much initializes everything when it's pulling from a database.

Comment: Thanks it was successful with this question on the error [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740877/asp-net-mvc3-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error)